# Blueimp upload - discard original file

Tags: jquery, file-upload, blueimp

I successfully create several image versions but I don't want to write the original file.
What is the correct way to prevent the original uploaded file being saved?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways. I did the following:

1. In the index.php class that you may found in *server/php* folder you have to: *(i)* check if there is another file in your upload folder with the same name of the one you are uploading; *(ii)* eventually rename that file or move it in another folder (or do what you want).
2. Let the code provided in the file with **class.php** extension works as usual.

Another strategy is to pass another filename to be used *in vece* of the one provided through the input form. In that case, you have to edit the method `trim_file_name()` in the file with **class.php** extension:

```
    protected function trim_file_name($name, $type, $index) {
      //BlueImp original code....

      $file_name ='name.xyz'//Your new name here;

      return $file_name;
    }
```